# AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() not fired

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, android-adapterview

My Adapter is set like this:

```android
userList = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.userList);
userListAdapter = new UserListAdapter(this, R.layout.user_list, getUserList());
userList.setAdapter(userListAdapter);
```

**function getUserList() return ArrayList UserList**

Like that the list is showed no problem on that.

But when I do this:

```android
userList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d("MyTag","kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk");
            }
        });
```

the Log.d is not fired.
I looked up in the console is shows **D/AbsListView: onTouchUp() mTouchMode : 1**

My Xmls activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/userList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
</ListView>
```

user_list.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="60"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:hint="Upd"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:hint="Del"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to fire a click on hole Listview Item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter make one interface for handle click event like below code..

```
onItemClickListner onItemClickListner;

public void setOnItemClickListner(UserAdapter.onItemClickListner onItemClickListner) {
    this.onItemClickListner = onItemClickListner;
}

public interface onItemClickListner{
   public void onItemClick();
}
```

when any control used to click event like hole layout click event used below code in adapter ..In adapter getView() method

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout=view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickListner.onItemClick();
        }
    });
```

after when you bind adapter in list view then after called below ...

```
        userListAdapter.setOnItemClickListner(new UserAdapter.onItemClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello world",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```